# How do I use AutoHotKey to read the text at the mouse location?

Tags: autohotkey, screen-scraping

I can read the entire window text using WinGetText() but I am trying to get the text at the current mouse location.

I've found several examples on the AutoHotKey forums but they are all very old (from 2007-2009) and the samples no longer work and in many cases the required files are no longer available.

Is this possible? How would could it be done?

Answer (score 0):

If you can tolerate OCR issues (i.e., garbled data sometimes or incorrect characters), there are working examples on the AHK forums using the GDIP OCR library to screen-capture a window around the mouse and then OCR it back into text for you.  Not pretty but it works for some things.